# How do processes branch out when you use fork() in a for loop?

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, fork

`fork()` calls outside a loop are easy to figure out, but when they are inside a loop I find it difficult. Can anyone figuratively explain how the processes branch out with an example like this one?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        fork();
        printf("hi");
        fork();
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, this would be the case:

- There is one "hi" printed with each process (abbreviated as proc)
- Each fork doubles the number of process (each process spawns one child)

The calculation could be done by following each event:

- start: 1 proc
- fork: 2 x 1 = 2 procs
- print: 2 procs -> **2 hi's**
- fork: 2 x 2 = 4 procs
- fork: 2 x 4 = 8 procs
- print: 8 procs -> **8 hi's**
- fork: 2 x 8 procs -> 16 procs

Now we add up the the number of hi's:

2 + 8 = **10 hi's in total**

However, this is not necessarily the case. On different systems, you may get different results.

A call to fork() causes a child process to be spawned that is identical to the parent.
If there is any *buffering* done when printing stdout and the buffers are not flushed before the next fork, then the child will appear to print when it "should not have". Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin) question for some details on buffering.

This causes a different number of hi's to be printed an different systems.

Answer (score 1):

Just unroll the loop:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    fork();
    printf("hi");
    fork();
    fork();
    printf("hi");
    fork();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: No. its not like that , by your explanation , there must be 16 "Hi"s but actually there are only 6 ...

Comment: there are 12 http://ideone.com/bUNDZ note that there is to printf after the second fork in the loop

Comment: i am seeing inconsistent results http://ideone.com/QMesr http://ideone.com/gXVxW. could it be dur to exit(0) that kills child processes before they reached the print?

Comment: Actually, "hi" gets printed 32 times, which is easier to see if you redirect the output to a file. If you do, you may also see some null bytes. I suspect that it is not entirely safe to call `printf` after a fork (see the caveat at the end of `man printf`). Interestingly, I do not see the null bytes if I pipe the output into `hexdump`.

Comment: @Gir I am seeing the same behavior replacing `exit` with `return`.

Comment: i added fflush(0) after each printf and now get the expected 10 prints

Comment: Each process inherits the open file descriptors from its parent, which means all of the processes end up trying to write to the same file from `printf`; this is bound to be unpredictable.

Comment: Its not like that...I found out how to do. there are totally 4 fork()s .Lets see one by one . First fork,there are two processes , thus 2 his... second and third fork make the total no of processes as 8 processes , thus 8 more His... fourth fork doesnt affect us. thus total no of his is 2+8 = 10  ...

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        fork();
        printf("hi from pid %d\n",getpid());
        fork();
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Now i've piped the output to fk.out.

```
[aft@kruki sf]$ cat fk.out 
hi from pid 6698
hi from pid 6698
hi from pid 6699
.......................
```

Now look at this :

```
[aft@kruki sf]$ cat fk.out | awk '{print $4}' | sort | uniq | wc -l

8
```

There, you have it, you have 8 processes !. Don't coun't hi's. Because stdin buffer will switched back and forth, so counting hi's will be ambiguous.